# update title of selected row in Uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm using the following code to get the selected cell in the UiTableView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Mofify the cell here
    }
```

when i change the cell text or color it does not make any change in the actual UitableView

Comment: How are you setting the cell text and/or color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you reload the cell. Use:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];
```

You should keep track of which cell was selected, and update the cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I don't know why the text isn't updating for you when you change it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but even if you get it to work, it will revert if you scroll that cell off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView is a subclass of UIView and UIView has this method to force it's refresh

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplay
```

But if you don't take that change into account in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you may never see the change.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell has the -titleLabel method which returns a UILabel. Then you might use the setText: and -setColor: methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

1. Set the backgroundColor property of the UITableViewCell.
2. Set the backgroundColor property of the UILabel (may not do what you need).
3. Set the backgroundView property if the UITableViewCell to a custom class you make by subclassing UIView, where you create a label and color.

Also, you can't just change the cell color, you need to have a data source from which cellForRowAtIndexPath: reads, which sets the cell color there. This way, the color change will persist.